# WLAN repeater and parental control on router

Tags: wireless-networking, parental-controls, repeater

is it possible to use parental control on a router with a WLAN client conntected?

If i use the MAC of the repeater all clients using this repeater are disconnected via the parental control. But I just want to deny just one client.

Asus DSL-N55U-B FW: 3.0.0.4.374_1397-g3827650

Comment: Thanks for your quick response: I think it is more a general question - e.g. it would be helpful on which level of the OSI model a WLAN repeater is working. Does the router get the IP from the repeater (higher level) or the IP from the client that uses the repeater (lower level)?   Asus DSL-N55U-B FW: 3.0.0.4.374_1397-g3827650

Comment: Fritz WLAN repeater just pluged in AC mains. It does what it should do: Expand the Wireless LAN range. On the router firmware I can select the MAC or the IP of the client for setup parental control. At the end the router software uses the MAC, because every IP I select is converted to the MAC. I have found at wikipedia that a normal repeater (not WLAN) and hubs are working on layer 1. So no IP is involved. But isn't a WLAN repeater working on layer 2 or higher?

Comment: It seems to me that I have found a way that works: I use a fix IP on the client instead a dynamic via  DHCP from router. Now it seems to work. But it would be great if someone can explain why and how it works.